micro-ros on Pico 2
Many questions and instructions I found about micro-ros and Pico are about the original Pico (on Humble.) Following those instructions that produce a UF2 don't work on a Pico 2 (on Jazzy Jalisco.)
Can anyone provide guidance?

Could you share the error(s)?

There is no error. I follow github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_raspberrypi_pico_sdk. After Step 2 "make", I copy the generated uf2 to the pico's BOOTSEL drive and then nothing happens. The uf2 is not processed.
